# React Antd Modal Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ModalProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

After upgrading to React 18 I have the following issue with Antd.

When using a component from Antd (Modal, Dialog, ...) it gives me this error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: ReactNode; ref: ForwardedRef<unknown>; className: string; visible: true; onCancel: (() => void) | undefined; onOk: undefined; footer: null; closable: false; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ModalProps'.   Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ModalProps'.
```

Here is my component:

```
function TransitionsModal(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const {
    open,
    onClose,
    children
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      {open &&
        <Modal
          className="flex items-center justify-center"
          visible={open}
          onCancel={onClose}
          onOk={undefined}
          footer={null}
          closable={false}>
          {children}
        </Modal>
      }
    </div>

  );
}
```

And here my Props:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode,
  open: boolean,
  onClose?: () => void
}
```

I use node 17.8.0

Comment: I was unable to reproduce it with React 18.0, Antd 14.19.5 - you can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-modal-fq3nqo?file=/index.tsx) for reference.

Comment: @tromgy Looking at the sandbox, the error shows up in the TransitionsModal, did you not see it ? It takes some time to show the error

Comment: Nope, I don't see any errors. Tried in a different browser as well just to make sure there was nothing cached.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should use

```
"@types/react": "17.0.39"
```

instead of

```
"@types/react": "18.0.3"
```

because react18 @types is not yet compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is related to latest updates of types in react 18. In order to avoid this error if you use yarn one solution would be be to use resolutions in package.json with some lower version of react. This way your dependency will be instructed to use types form diff version.

Example:

```
"resolutions": { "@types/react": "17.0.30" }
```